# Python - Best way to append a sequence of numbers to a text file?

Tags: python

Let's say that I have textfile of a series of numbers that looks like this:

```
18,18,19,19,16,20,19,20,18,20,21
```

That's only a preview of hundreds of numbers separated by commas. I want to be able to manipulate the data in python in a [list]. So I have a variable src that I want to append the integer values to from the text file.

Like so:

```
text_file = open("sequence.txt","r")
src = []

for entry in text_file.read():
    if(entry != ','):
        src.append(int(entry))
```

Obviously this get's rid of the ',' between each entry in my textfile however values like 20 in the textfile will be appended to the list as two separate entries [2,0].

What's the best way to append these values ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Is all the data on a single line? Is the separator always a single comma, with no spaces?

Comment: How does the text file look ? Does it contain only one line ?

Answer (score 1):

```
text_file = open("sequence.txt", "r")
src = text_file.read()
src = src.split(',')
src = map(int, src) #this works on python 2.x, for python3 do src = list(map(int, src))
print src
text_file.close()
```

Output:

```
[18, 18, 19, 19, 16, 20, 19, 20, 18, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the text file line by line; each line is read as a string.  You can use that string's *.split()* method to separate it into a list of strings (on the commas) and you can use the *int()* function to interpret each of those resulting strings as an integer.

All of that looks like this:

```
src = list()
with open("sequence.txt","r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        src.append([int(x) for x in line.split(',')])
```

... though this does not gracefully handle any corrupt input.

(Exception handling with your own wrapper around the *int()* function or in other ways is left as an exercise).

Incidentally the details of this question (and my answer) are about how to read integers in from a file; one in which the values are separated by commas but which generally is not conforming to the conventional "CSV" (comma separated values) file format.

To append more values to the file one would simply open the file in append mode and write the new values to it (adding the new values as a new line by default).  Text files which fail to terminate with a newline character are problematic for many common utilities and programming techniques.  (Effectively, it's necessary to treat that last line as a special case, as though it were from a binary file rather than as regular text).

The code for writing to of these comma separated text/integers file would look something like:

```
with open('sequence.txt','a') as output:
    output.write(', '.join(src))
    output.write('\n')
```

... and that should be sufficient unless I'm not fully understanding your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If the text file only contains one single line you can do it much simpler

```
src = list(map(int, open("sequence.txt","r").read().split(",")))
```

Of course it would be better to also close the file after reading, so

```
with open("sequence.txt","r") as f:
    src = list(map(int, f.read().split(",")))
```